# How to define a multidimensional array when is undefined?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

This is my code:

```
    if(notas_insert[selected_n_document] === "undefined"){
        notas_insert[selected_n_document] = [];
    }
    if(notas_insert[selected_n_document][selected_version] === "undefined"){
        notas_insert[selected_n_document][selected_version] = [];
    }
    if(notas_insert[selected_n_document][selected_version]["index"] === "undefined"){
    notas_insert[selected_n_document][selected_version]["index"] = 0;
    }
    notas_insert[selected_n_document][selected_version][notas_insert[selected_n_document][selected_version]["index"]] = notas_pre;
    notas_insert[selected_n_document][selected_version]["index"]++;
```

I get this error:

```
Cannot read property '1' of undefined
```

How can I create an array within an array with code, because If I write in the console:

```
notas_insert[selected_n_document] = [];
```

I no longer get the error on the third line, but for some reason it doesn't seem to work if I do it within the code.

Comment: Don't put quotes around undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your condition like this

```
if(typeof notas_insert[selected_n_document][selected_version] === "undefined")
```

Comment: This will fail if `selected_n_document` is undefined

Comment: It's won't :) that's the beauty of `typeof` if it's not defined with will return a string named undefined

Comment: I just did it in the console...try it for yourself, it throws a TypeError.

Answer (score 0):

I'd set up defaults with something like this:

```
var doc = notas_insert[selected_n_document] || [];
var version = doc[selected_version] || [];
```

etc